# Path to html page loading it from within a folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have index.html page in which i am loading a page headercontent.html by jquery load funtion(it is html page for header content like menus and submenus of my website) in it works nice . But i have some html pages on folder named 
pc-->samsung-printers service.html, in this page load function is not loading the headercontent.html. I have tried the serveral path like ...

```
$("#includefile").load("headercontent.html"); 
   or
$("#includefile").load("..headercontent.html"); 
 or
 $("#includefile").load("./headercontent.html"); 
  or
$("#includefile").load("../headercontent.html");
```

For example:
i have website page like(website directory structure..)

```
index.html
headercontent.html(this page is loaded in every page bcoz this header 
content)
plan.html

now there is folder named PC
PC
->care.html


 code of care.html
<html>
<head>

<script 
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 

$(function()

{

$("#includefile").load("headercontent.html"); 

});

</script>

</head>

<body style="overflow:hidden">

   <div class="pageWrapper">


        <header class="headermenus" id="includefile">


         </header>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

what should be the exact path of my header.html file which can be loaded succesfully in care.html page.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why do you not use the full path to the file?

Comment: how to use full path according to my directory structure..

Comment: Only you know what the full path is to the folder and the file. For example, `"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"` is the full path to the file `"jquery.min.js"`

Comment: suppose my html file is in:  D:\onlinepc - Copy\headercontent.html and want to load this file in another html file path is: D:\onlinepc - Copy\pc\care.html.. here i want to load the headercontent.html in care.html page with load funtion as above; like $("#includefile").load("headercontent.html"); ,but it doest work,if you can give me right path for this html(headercontent.html) file.

Comment: Then use that path. Why are there space characters in directory name?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I would say the line with the load function should read

```
$("#includefile").load("../headercontent.html");
```

Comment: Yes!  actually i want  to load the headercontent.html page in care.html page as above .but gave this path but does'nt load in my div in care.html page.